# Is it always possible to balance a 4-legged table?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, physics

A perfectly symmetrical small 4-legged table is standing in a large room with a continuous but uneven floor. Is it always possible to position the table in such a way that it doesn't wobble, i.e. all four legs are touching the floor?

No tricks. No [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking). Serious question (with real-life applications too!) with a serious answer.

<sub>This might look like it'd fit better on Lifehacks.SE, but the answer has a nice mathematical proof/formula [depending on whether it's yes/no; I won't give the game away!] which is surprisingly simple and elegant.</sub>

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan It's a problem that (like many people) I've often faced in real life, and I thought it'd make a good puzzle. Not exactly an original idea, but I didn't copy it from anywhere, so I guess it's OK to credit me. And thanks :-)

Comment: What if the continuous uneven floor resembles a bed of nails where each nail is longer than a table leg and they are spaced such that there is no combination of four nails that the legs can touch at the same time, nor is there a space between nails such that all four legs could touch the ground at the bottom?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Come on, seriously! I said no tricks :-)

Comment: What if the floor of the entire room is a slightly uneven, extremely steep slope?

Comment: When you say perfectly symmetrical do you mean all 4 legs are the exact same height (symmetry on both axes), or that two legs are one height and the other two legs can be another height (symmetrical)?

Comment: @Kingrames All 4: "perfectly symmetrical" meaning all possible kinds of symmetry.

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you made the table "astronomically small" and bigger than the planet, its legs would frame the planet and the underside of the "table" would become the new "floor", and the legs would all be touching the floor. At least that scenario checks out! ;)

Comment: Is the floor's surface continuously differentiable? Or simply continuous.

Comment: @corsiKa Simply continuous is enough. A crazy counterexample involving the blancmange function would probably count as a "trick" anyway though :-)

Comment: Too easy if you've already seen [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuF-WB7mD6k) that poses and answers the question... >_>

Comment: @randal'thor I was actually thinking of something shaped like a quilt or a mattress.

Comment: What sort of geometry constitutes a floor? Do we assume that every vertical line passes through the floor in exactly one point? It's not clear what distinguishes a trick from a legitimate floor we need to deal with.

Comment: Define a floor to be sufficiently steep, and the table will just fall off ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor "perfectly symmetrical" still isn't clear to me. "all possible kinds of symmetry" doesn't cut it: there's no such thing as a circularly symmetric four-legged table, unless you count nested hollow cylinders as "legs". Can you please give a clearer definition?

Comment: And why is Ian McDonald's remark or something involving the blancmage function be a "trick"? I don't see anything in either that doesn't satisfy the condition of a continuous floor: both are perfectly mathematically valid examples of continuous surfaces, and I don't see lateral thinking involved in either.

Comment: @PeterOlson "Perfectly symmetrical" means as symmetrical as something 4-y can be: 2 axes of reflectional symmetry and 4 angles of rotational symmetry. It could be a square table or a round one, and the legs could be cuboids or cylinders (though we're modelling them as lines)

Comment: You could ammend the question to be mathematically sound ( so the nails longer than table legs counter doesn't work ): You want to place a square on a continous floor (continous 2-dimensional function f(x,y) = z) so that all 4 corner-points of the square touch the floor ( for each of the 4 points the following holds true: f(px,py) = pz )

Comment: Note that this is trivially true for a 3-legged table because "through three non collinear points, there is exactly one plane".

Comment: Shame about the `No lateral-thinking`, I was going to start with no because "The floor is lava", followed by Rubber, Gravel, Grating, Water or a Whale.

Comment: technically the "nails longer than table legs" still allows the table to be well balanced, but on the nails, rather than the legs.

Comment: It has been correctly answered; I'm just waiting for the activity to subside before I accept. @TobiaTesan Exactly! :-) I was considering putting that into the question just to make it more interesting.

Comment: Have we decided that "uneven floor" means "horizontal plane, but with flaws -- peaks and valleys -- which are considerably shorter than the table's height"? It seems a lot of people are being reprimanded for "lateral thinking", though the question doesn't comment on the floor's unevenness.

Comment: @Kingrames, I agree that it would be balanced, but the puzzle also specifies "all four legs are touching the floor".

Comment: Seems to me that the question is trying to have it both ways, as in mathematical model vs practice. On one hand it seems that the intended definition of a “table that doesn't wobble” is very mathematical (ends of legs are points and it suffices that the table can be rotated in a way such that all four touch the floor at some instant), but on the other hand people suggesting “unrealistic” floors get accused of trickery… If the point is to showcase a single pre-determined (albeit neat) solution, perhaps the question should define the desired model of table, floor, and wobble more accurately.

Comment: @Arkku You've put your finger on what many people have missed. The TABLE is a mathematical ideal ("perfectly symmetrical" and so on), while the FLOOR is a practical imperfect thing ("uneven").

Comment: @randal'thor  Ah now I see it's a trick question then.  A theoretical (ideal) table can't possibly be  positioned on a practical floor since the table exists only as an abstraction.  Therefore there are no legs at all to touch the floor.  Therefore the answer is No.

Comment: Lifehacks.SE, indeed. Related: [Stop keyboard wobble](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/stop-keyboard-wobble-due-to-uneven-desk/7491#7491).

Comment: In real life the answer is "no"

Comment: How do you define an "uneven" floor?

Comment: @MaskedMan Just an ordinary real-life floor which isn't perfectly flat.

Comment: What about an uneven floor in a room whose radius is only 1% larger than the radius of the table. No trickery with the table. No trickery with the floor. Still can't guarantee all four legs touch the ground at once.

Comment: @IanMacDonald See the deleted answer from Aura.

Comment: @randal'thor well, then what about columns, other tables, people, or any number of other obstacles that are commonplace in rooms?

Comment: I had been annoyed by such wobbling many times. Then after I started learning calculus in 1997, I quickly realized that there was a simple algorithm to fix the wobbling. I can confirm that the solution has real life applications, and that it does indeed work.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with a video from numberphile, does it?

Comment: I added a real answer, I show a floor that won't allow a table to be placed(a real house may actually have that floor). Do you think you are going to accept it (it miss a real mathematical proof but at least has 1 falsificable statement in the end).

Comment: @Luke, that's fine.  The table doesn't need to end up horizontal, it just needs to end up with all four feet touching the floor.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The answer is

> yes!

Here's why:

> Imagine that the table can pass through the floor. We're going to call one leg the "floating leg" - the other three are going to always be on the floor. Now, after we rotate the table a quarter turn, the floating leg is going to be above the floor if it was originally below, or vice versa. By the intermediate value theorem, it will be exactly on the floor at one point in that rotation.

More detailed proof:

> Three legs of the table define a plane. Define the "offset" of a leg to be the distance above the floor if the other three legs are placed on the floor directly - negative if below, positive if above. In any arbitrary placement, the offset of any two adjacent legs will be positive and negative. (WLOG assume the one on the left is positive.) Offset is a continuous function because it's the distance from the floor. If you start with a positive offset on leg A and rotate the table 90° to the right, the offset on leg A (now in the original position of another leg) will be negative. This means that at some point, offset was 0, therefore the table was completely touching the floor.

Comment: What I really like about this solution is that it's genuinely useful. In a real-life situation, you *actually can* plonk 3 legs on the ground and rotate until it's stable. Normally there's far more intermediate stages of abstraction between a mathematical proof and a real-life method!

Comment: @randal'thor: Yeah, it was really surprising to me to discover that this actually worked in real life! (Of course, nobody at the dinner wanted to hear *why* it worked...)

Comment: My only concern is ridiculous slants where the cent of mass cannot be between the points of contact.

Comment: @Deusovi "Yes" may very well be the answer, but I am not convinced that your explanation using the intermediate value theorem is sufficient. I can see how it would work if the table has only 1 leg, but with more than 1 leg, it is possible that at no point during the rotation that all legs are exactly on the floor. Please elaborate a little further if you believe your answer is correct.

Comment: [Watch the numberphile youtube on that same question.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuF-WB7mD6k)

Comment: I feel like this assumes that the table has rotational symmetry. Can we still do it without rotational symmetry assumption?

Comment: This answer assumes that the table's height and weight place the center of gravity above the footprint of the legs.

Comment: @JustinOhms: You just have to have all the legs touching the floor. They can be bolted down if necessary.

Comment: @Aura: I went into more detail in the proof.

Comment: @FarazMasroor: The rotational symmetry was given in the problem.

Comment: @Goinghamateur: It never says the table has to *stay* balanced, just that it has to be able to touch the floor with all four legs.

Comment: @Deusovi Well, not if you don't read the question =p

Comment: This answer doesn't explain nearly enough about the rotation. Are we rotating the table around some axis? No possible axis seems to work. Are we rotating it in such a way that three legs remain planted on the ground? It isn't even clear that a table can always be rotated in such a manner. The definition of "offset" seems to assume a canonical way of going from an arbitrary table position to one where three specified legs are on the ground, and it isn't clear which way you'd do that.

Comment: @user2357112: Rotating around the center, and at every point tilting the table such that the three legs remain on the ground.

Comment: @Deusovi: Why would that guarantee you go from a positive offset to a negative one? And how do you prove such a rotation is always possible, or that the required tilting won't require sudden jumps that defeat the continuity you're relying on?

Comment: @user2357112: Because in any unstable position, the offsets of any two adjacent legs have opposite signs. And if all three contact points are continuously moving (and never collinear), then the plane defined by them is continuously moving as well.

Comment: @Deusovi: But you're just asserting that the three contact points move continuously. How do you know that the corrective tilting can always be done continuously?

Comment: @user2357112 The floor is continuous, as stated in the question.

Comment: I believe the yes answer is only valid if the legs of the table end in infinitely sharp and narrow points. If instead, as might be in the case in a still perfect but realistic table, the legs end in finite square flats, or cylindrical flats, or smooth convex 'knobs' etc, then the answer is almost certainly 'No'.

Comment: @Deusovi: It's not clear how you get from the continuity of the floor to the continuity of the tilting. Continuity alone isn't enough; it's not too difficult to come up with surfaces continuous but not quite floor-like (for example, a donut) where the rotation doesn't work.

Comment: Also, you say that after the rotation completes, leg A is at the original position of a different leg. How is that supposed to work? If it started out off the ground, then simply asserting that it ends up in the original position of a different leg (which started out on the ground) is asserting that the rotation ends with all four legs on the ground. Also, it's not clear that the rotation and tilting wouldn't have caused the table to drift significantly from its original location.

Comment: @user2357112: I assumed that the floor was roughly planar. (And it *would* work on a donut - just rotate around the center.) As to your second comment, leg A would be at the original position of leg B if it was anchored and C was lifted (or pushed downwards); and the rotation would not cause the table to drift because the center of the table is kept on the same vertical axis.

Comment: @Penguino: True - I *did* assume a 'perfect' table (infinitely thin legs).

Comment: I'm not even convinced that a table with three legs will work. Even disregarding the issues concerning rotation and managing the offset of the fourth leg, how do you guarantee that the other three legs can fit?

Comment: @PeterOlson Fix two points.  Then the third point will be on a circle in a plane prependicular to the line between the first two points.  This circle will intersect the surface at some point, hence you can always place three points on a surface.

Comment: @Taemyr But there's no guarantee that the configuration when the third point hits the surface (or even just fixing the two points, for that matter) is a valid configuration, unless you permit the table to go through the surface.

Comment: @PeterOlson You only need the final configuration, ie. the one with all four legs on the floor, to be valid.  To prove that this configuration exists the answer explicitly consider cases where the table legs extend below the floor.

Comment: @Taemyr I'm not talking about the table legs, I'm talking about the surface of the table going through the floor, which isn't addressed.

Comment: @PeterOlson It's addressed in the comments. "I assumed that the floor was roughly planar."

Comment: @Taemyr Why can we make that assumption? The question only says "continuous", which could be all sorts of crazy things. And how do you even define "roughly planar"? Without a good definition the answer isn't much better than "we can always balance the table because I only allow floors where it's always possible to balance the table".

Comment: @PeterOlson One could argue that this assumption is unwarranted.  However OP describes it as an uneven floor in a large room and stresses the real-life application. - And any floor on a normal room would be close enough to a plane for this to work.

Comment: @Deusovi  The original question precludes the possibility of bolting the table to the floor in several ways.  Even if we exclude the notion that "standing" does not necessarily mean "free standing", the question implies that a table that does not have all 4 legs in contact with the floor would "wobble".  This assertion implies that the legs are not physically attached to the floor, since a table that were bolted to the floor with even 1 leg wouldn't "wobble".  The question also implies that gravity is the means of adhesion by specifying the surface as a "floor" not as a ceiling or a wall.

Comment: @Justin: Well, sliding isn't wobbling.

Comment: @Goinghamateur: actually the question states that the"table is standing" this implies balance.   i.e.   "is" (current static tense) "standing" (having upright position)

Comment: @Deusovi  this is further argument against allowing any configuration in which the center of gravity is not directly in line with the footprint.  Even if the table were bolted to the floor, if the center of gravity is located outside of the footprint of the legs, the table would then be at a slant, it would not be "upright".

Comment: @Justin It never says that the table has to be upright, just that it doesn't have to wobble.

Comment: @Deusovi  Yes sliding isn't wobbling.  But that doesn't support your argument.   And yes the question does say that the table needs to be upright.  Look up the definition of "standing".   Plus, a table that isn't upright isn't a table, it is at best an easel.

Comment: @Deusovi,  also assuming that the legs are "infinitely sharp" violates the questions rules of "no lateral-thinking."  and "Serious question (with real-life applications too!)"  Unless you can produce a "real-life" table with "infinitely sharp" legs, the assumptions that you made for your answer directly violate the OPs original question and is therefore invalid.

Comment: @Justin Like you said, it's not going to be tilted that much - if the table was tilted so much as to be better as an easel than as a table, then the floor would not be a "wobbly floor" as much as a pit of spikes. And standing does not have to be perfectly upright.

Comment: @Justin and the infinitely thin legs can be easily patched by replacing "distance from the floor" with "minimum distance from the floor over the leg's bottom" - still continuous, so it still applies.

Comment: @Deosovi, glad you see my point, if the table IS tilted so much that the center of gravity is outside the footprint of the legs (therefore requiring the legs to be bolted to the floor) It's not standing and it's not even a table at I thin the point is that being a table implies that you can actually place something on it an have it remain in place through gravity and friction.

Comment: @Justin: Yes, I agree. I read the question as implicitly excluding that possibility (and sometimes you could put really heavy weights at the bottom of the legs), but I understand what you mean.

Comment: The leg goes from offset negative to offset exactly zero after rotation of 90 degrees. So no proof that it has passed across offset zero.

Comment: @arivero: No, it goes from offset negative to offset positive. And offset 0 is when all four legs are on the ground.

Comment: @user2357112: I agree with your objections, and have posted what I think is a correct solution, both mathematically and physically. I did not write out a formal proof so I may have made some intuition-based error, but see if you're convinced!

Comment: @PeterOlson: You are right about that too, and I believe the comments I gave in my answer address that issue at least partially. But I don't have a good way of dealing with funny non-straight legs yet.

Comment: Now what if the table is rectangular?

Answer (score 49):

> Yes.

The reason is actually simpler and more intuitive than the other answers:

> It's obvious that the table can always stand on three legs, because the ends of two legs define a line, and the third leg can be brought into contact by rotating around that line.  Then, rotating the table around a vertical axis, the fourth leg *must* touch the floor before any of the other legs becomes unable to touch, because the fourth leg touching is the reason one of the other legs wouldn't be able to touch.

Comment: -1 this answer is identical to the accepted answer while not offering anything new.

Comment: @MarchHo Now, as when I wrote this, there *is* no accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the highest voted one, but my point stands.

Comment: @MarchHo My answer may be mathematically *equivalent* (and if it is, please elaborate on how); but it is certainly not *identical*.

Comment: +1 because you're *right*, unlike several of the other answers. Although @MarchHo is right that this is equivalent to the top answer and describes the same method for stabilising the table, it's also more intuitive (if less rigorous) since it doesn't mention the intermediate value theorem (which is admittedly 'obvious').

Comment: This gets my +1 for being the clearest explanation, despite not being a new theory.

Comment: I find the gaps in this proof more intuitively clear than the gaps in Deusovi's proof ("the offset of any two adjacent legs will be positive and negative").

Comment: Much clearer than the accepted answer.

Comment: except how do you demonstrate that the fourth foot **must** touch the floor? can't it stay woobling forever? (for example if the table is standing on an elevation of the floor where you can only set 3 feet at a time?)

Comment: This answer doesn't show that it's necessary for another leg not to be able to touch at some point.

Comment: @MarchHo it clarifies that the "rotation" is keeping the three other legs attached to the floor. The currently most voted answer does not argue it.

Comment: @njzk2 It's true that this breaks down if the local radius of curvature of the floor is smaller than around half the distance between the chair legs.  The OP doesn't quantify *how* uneven the floor is...

Comment: @MarchHo at the time of writing this, 13 upvotes say your point does not stand.

Comment: @arivero: The other answer says to rotate the table while keeping the 3 legs on the floor but uses different wording: `We're going to call one leg the "floating leg" - the other three are going to always be on the floor`. The other answer is more specific, it states that the solution WILL BE FOUND within a quarter turn.

Comment: @slebetan So it has rotated a quarter, a grounded leg is now in the position of the floating leg, and the floating is now in the position of a grounded, but not grounded... yep of course everything is true, but the real argument to explain it is explicitly n this answer.

Comment: Like the other answer, this is incorrect because there is in general **no** axis around which a nonzero rotation keeps three legs touching the floor!

Comment: @user21820 But you can *always* repeat the step where you rotate around the line defined by the ends of two legs until the third touches.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: That proves **nothing**! You **claimed** that you can rotate around a **vertical** axis, but once you do that **all three legs** will leave the floor. There is no way you can fix it without doing something like what I did in my answer.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: Worse still, by "leave the floor" it includes the possibility that they may all pass through the floor on the slightest rotation around a vertical axis.

Comment: @user21820 For *any* rotation through *any* axis, you can always repeat the process of placing three legs on the floor.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: Frankly, please learn first-order logic and proper real analysis. Your answer as it is makes the **false** claim that you can rotate around a **vertical** axis **such that the fourth leg must touch ... before ... unable to touch ...**. If you try to fix it by saying that you repeat the placing process for each angle, you have **no control** over the result and can neither keep three legs on the floor throughout (since you have to life the table to repeat the process!) nor reach the desired final position!

Comment: @user21820 My intuitive explanation is the [classic accepted one](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/strange-but-true-turning/).  You're not just arguing with me.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: That is the **fallacy** of appealing to authority. If you are wrong, you are wrong regardless of how many people you quote.

Comment: @user21820 Of course.  But when you find yourself in disagreement with an overwhelming majority of authorities, it *suggests* that maybe you made a mistake.  In fact, it's *likely* that you made a mistake, unless you can find the specific error that the authorities have made.  And you have not done that.  You're just gibbering.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: I have already pointed out the mistake. And you are making yet another **fallacy** of popular opinion. This reminds me of the time when many people believed that the sun and moon both revolved around the same centre Earth. I am a mathematician and so I know what I am talking about. You and the vast majority are not and hence cannot even see your error. As I said, if you learn first-order logic and real analysis properly, you will readily understand what I've said.

Comment: @user21820 I am not a mathematician, but the people on whose expertise I am relying are.  This explanation was taught to me by a math professor.  You may be a mathematician, but as far as anyone can tell (including other mathematicians), you're analogous to the 1% of climate scientists who rejects climate change.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: I'm sorry you're absolutely wrong, and hopefully you'll see why eventually. Please do go and ask your math professor whether what I say is correct or not. You have to understand that many mathematicians do not give people the proper explanation because the prerequisite mathematical understanding is too high for them. That is why the article you linked to presents nothing more than an extremely handwavy explanation. As I said, if you actually bother to learn logic and real analysis, you will agree with me. At the moment you clearly know nearly nothing about either.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: And please go ahead and ask at Math SE as well to get multiple mathematicians' opinions other than just mine and your professor's. Your audience here are mostly just like you and of course they don't see any problems. The website you link to is most probably written by people just like you as well, which means they do not actually understand the mathematical articles that they claim to cite.

Answer (score 22):

The answer is:

> No.

Reason by provable test case:

> We have a table that is a solid, 3 foot tall, wide, and long, cube of wood, with 4 very short stubby legs on one side (we'll say 2 inches). If standing on a continuous but uneven floor, Say, a simple hexagonal pattern of half-spherical domes (5 inch high domes) (stylized like bubble paper, of course) the domes would lift the table off the floor, preventing it from balancing. At no point could you guarantee stable footing.

...Here's some images to help illustrate the problem.

> [image: A grid of bubbles]

Here's a grid of bubbles covering the floor. we can surmise that a table could put its legs between these bubbles and touch the floor, but only on the condition that the floor gives space to do so. if not, then you could "balance" the table only in name, on top of the bubbles, but we all know it wouldn't last.

> [image: A hex grid of bubbles]

When we switch to a hex-based formation, we see more problems. Firstly, depending on the dimensions of the table, it might not be possible to fit the legs inbetween the bubbles anymore. (In real life, tables don't have massless, frictionful legs because that would be pretty frickin dangerous. This question has what I like to call a spherical cow error [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow ] - Although it might be useful in real life scenarios, in order to say that it ALWAYS will be helpful in real life scenarios you have to keep adding criteria to the problem to eliminate "edge cases" which are valid concerns for other people, you just don't realize that they count just as much as you do)

> [image: A hex grid of bubbles from above]

From above, the situation is a lot more clear. Square tables are going to have a hell of a time trying to balance on this kind of floor, and most often, they're just going to remain in a "good enough" position where they still slide a bit and you just have to remember not to do anything on that table that requires stability.

Final verdict:

> The table can't be guaranteed to balance on the floor in any situation where the table legs have mass (and therefore volume).

Comment: Ah, c'mon - I said no tricks or lateral thinking! :-)

Comment: Stubby legs doesn't count as tricks! Don't discriminate against short tables!

Comment: Why stubby legs?  You just need a floor that's more uneven than the leg length.

Comment: @randal'thor I don't understand, why does this count as a trick rather than a straightforward counterexample?

Comment: @PeterOlson The question was meant to be about a real-life problem. Mathematically you can come up with pathological counterexamples to loads of things, but in real life anything that works practically for all cases you're likely to come across is good enough.

Comment: ^ and look at me sounding like an *applied* mathematician :-P

Comment: @randal'thor This isn't even pathological, though. I don't know about you, but I can easily imagine the floor and table described in this answer being possible to construct in real life (there's no fractals or any fancy mathematical techniques). If it's not possible in this instance, then the answer to "is it always possible" is a clear *no*.

Comment: @randal'thor Now you're discriminating against extremely uneven floors!

Comment: If it's 3 feet across but has two-inch 'legs', is it really still a table?

Comment: "still a table," sure. I mean I don't even have to make it a solid cube. There are plenty of tables in Japan that have extremely short feet and are very low to the ground. The situation given above just makes it more obvious that short stubby feet are the cause of the imbalance. You can easily see a Japanese table not working on a bump-covered floor.

Comment: I think the key to this counterexample is: Is it possible to construct a continuous but uneven floor in such a way that you can prevent a perfectly symmetrical table from balancing on it?

Comment: @randal'thor: you've already defined "doesn't wobble" as "all four legs are touching the floor", so it's not required that the table be in a stable equilibrium in this position (or even, strictly speaking, that it won't fall off should the floor be sloping, since by this definition plummeting is not wobbling). The fact that you've stated it this way should deal with most "tricks" by a means more definite than the value judgement, "if a room had a floor like that I wouldn't care whether or not I could put my table in it" ;-) So just take out the bit about the table "standing".

Comment: @SteveJessop Very good point! I wish you could deal with all these trick answers :-) In fact I don't even have to take out the "standing" bit: it's standing now, but is it possible to position it so it doesn't wobble (even if it's no longer standing)?

Comment: Well fundamentally, this being a "puzzle", a trick answer could be defined as "any correct answer other than the one I had in mind". But for obvious reasons that's not entirely satisfying to people who approach it as a practical problem, nor to people who approach it with a mathematical model different from the one you hoped for :-)

Comment: I've edited the response to add the promised pictures, courtesy of Unreal Engine 4 and the snipping tool. To replicate the success, you can just drag and drop a sphere, select it and hit end (which will have it snap to the floor), and then hold alt down while moving the spheres along the floor to duplicate them. This will allow you to position them and form patterns. Unreal Engine 4 is free, and so you lose nothing from trying it out yourself! (also thanks for the puzzle randy!)

Comment: @Kingrames I think that this exact case in the picture is not continuous

Comment: @dmg You can make it continuous by "smoothing" the floor, still I think such floor allows placing the table. I'm pretty sure with a hexagonal pattern the table can be placed. You need more exotic dispositions of spheres, and constraints on sphere sizes to get table misplaced. In example if table size is <= radius of spheres you can for sure always place it (2 legs on a sphere, the other 2 on the other sphere)

Answer (score 12):

The answer is

> no.

> The answers that say 'yes' seem to stop after showing how you can make all 4 legs reach the floor. However, not only is it sometimes impossible to make all 4 legs touch the floor (think floors with large troughs, mounds, or waves), even when they do, that condition alone does not mean it can be said the table is "balanced", "stable", or "doesn't wobble". Indeed, those answers accept out of hand that 3 legs of the table can touch the floor nicely, but no guarantee for such a condition is afforded anywhere in the problem statement.

> Even a modestly turbulent surface that you or I wouldn't have trouble walking on won't hold a table steady unless most of the surface of each foot contacts the floor. This would be impossible if the floor was relentlessly bumpy, like a gravel road or a rocky coastline. If you want a more sterile example, consider something like `z = sin x + cos y`. There are other, gravel-less ways to get this too. One is where the floor is large tiles that are flat but have a variety of slants. More real-life places come to mind. Speaking of real life, the table will not experience infinite friction with the ground (or with objects placed on it), which means a limit needs to be respected on how far off level the table can be before it simply falls over (or objects slide off).

In conclusion,

> there are many factors that determine how and whether or not a table wobbles on a surface. There are probably more than I realize, since I am not a physicist. As for this question, I do not think `a large room with a continuous but uneven floor` comes close to providing context sufficient to rule out the tendency to wobble.

Comment: As I said in a comment on the question, the legs are technically being modelled as lines, or at least the bottom of each leg is modelled as a point.

Comment: @randal'thor I don't understand your standard for being about a "real-life" problem. You reject [Kingrame's answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/20611/16013) and [Ian McDonald's comment](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20595/#comment64463_20595) on this basis even though they present surfaces that are perfectly feasible to produce in real life, while you reject this answer for pointing out real-life limitations because your question is about a mathematical model. What are you really asking about, real life or a mathematical model?

Comment: You shouldn't think of table legs as lines if you want this problem to transfer to the real world.

Comment: The table legs could still be cone-shaped though, i.e. the bottom of each one is a single point. That's enough to invalidate this answer, I think. In reality the leg bases *are* usually smaller than the bumps in the ground.

Comment: @randal'thor At least 99% of the tables I've seen do not have cone-shaped legs and could easily made wobbly by being placed on top of gravel, and at least 99% of the floors I've seen don't look like a bed of nails.  Why do you only seem to consider edge cases that point towards the answer being "yes"?

Comment: A more important point: can't stability be achieved by having the *centre* of the base of each leg resting on the ground? Even gravel is still continuous in real life.

Comment: @PeterOlson I'm not sure what you mean with the "bed of nails" remark. The only answers I've seen referring to bed-of-nails scenarios have been ones I've dismissed as "tricks". I'm assuming an ordinary real-world floor, continuous and reasonably shaped but not perfectly flat.

Comment: @Geoff: Even on very rough tiles or pebbly floors the solution of the other answers still work (turn the table up to 90 degrees). Try it. Only in really pathological situations (sidewalk smaller than table width forcing at least one of the legs to fall into the drain, hotel floor cratered by bombs etc.) will it not work. If you look at a surface and consider that surface a "floor" then the solution works. Seriously. Try it out.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is "YES"

Place the table on the floor, and label the legs, clockwise from above (A, B, C, D) and their points of contact on the floor (1, 2, 3, and 4) respectively. Note that despite the different labels, the four legs, by symmetry, must be identical in length.

If all four legs are in contact, then the condition is satisfied.

If not, then without loss of generality we can set Leg A as not in contact with Floor Point #1.

Then rotate the table by one-quarter turn clockwise, while allowing it to be supported by the floor throughout the rotation.

Now Leg A is at Point #2. and in contact with Point #2.  After all, Leg B was in contact before the rotation, and Leg A is identical to Leg B.

On the other hand, Leg D, formerly in contact with Point 4, has rotated around to Point 1, where it is out of contact, since it is replacing the identical Leg A, which was out of contact.

So Leg A made contact, while Leg D lost contact.  If Leg A made contact first, then at that point all four legs are in contact.  If Leg D left first, then the table is resting on two legs, and it tips over...

Modesty and honesty require that I credit Martin Gardner http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/strange-but-true-turning/

And yes, I did read ***and*** recall the original 1973 article...

Comment: I think this is somewhat better than Deusovi's answer, but it still assumes the existence of some continuous motion from the original position to the rotated position that keeps at least three legs on the ground at all times. It's not clear that you wouldn't run into a situation where leg D loses contact, the table tips over, and it lands on leg A.

Comment: I actually use this technique fairly regularly since I was first shown it as an undergrad in the faculty of Math at Waterloo in the late 70s. Much better than sticking paper under one leg and really does work whenever the issue is the floor rather than the table.

Comment: @user2357112: You seem to be missing the point. Deusovi's answer and this answer states that if you find a wobbly table at any restaurant in the world you can try turning the table 90 degrees and before reaching 90 degrees there WILL BE at least one angle at which all four legs touch the floor. On real-world restaurant floors with real-world tables you will not encounter a situation where leg D loses contact causing the table to tip over (if you do you can sue the owner)

Comment: @slebetman: *How do you know?* Even for quite ordinary floors, how do you know that such a thing won't happen, aside from having never seen it happen?

Comment: @user2357112: See Deusovi's answer

Comment: @slebetman: Deusovi's answer doesn't explain that either, and I've made similar comments on that answer.

Comment: @user2357112: It does explain that. Given a floor where the maximum unevenness is less than half the height of the table leg (this is defined by the OP's no-tricks specification, so no trick floors where a bump exists that is taller than the table - such a bump would not be a "floor" anyway, it would be a pole), there must be one configuration where the wobble switches between one pair of legs and another. If this is so then by the intermediate value theorem there must be at least one angle where the switch happens and this is where the table doesn't wobble.

Comment: @user2357112 To probe to opposite: that is to prove that the floor does not have a non-wobble configuration, then the table must always wobble on the same pair of legs. There are only two possible situations where such a thing is possible: one of the table legs is shorter than the others - this is eliminated by the OP's specification of a fully symmetrical table. The second possibility is that the floor is a spiral (basically a screw) and this is eliminated by the OP's specification of no trick floors.

Comment: @slebetman: "there must be one configuration where the wobble switches between one pair of legs and another" - *how do you know that*? You are making assumptions about what states are reachable from what other states. How do you know that for "non-trick" floors, if the table starts out in a wobbly state, there exists a continuous motion of the table that reaches a state with the table wobbling on the other pair of legs?

Comment: @user2357112: Because the only possible floor that would enable the table to wobble on only one pair of legs and not switch is a spiral. Now you must prove that there exist a continuous floor that is not a spiral where the table can only wobble on one pair and never switch.

Comment: @slebetman: No, the burden of proof is on the person claiming to have a solution. Simply asserting that there are no counterexamples is not a solution; it's as bad a non-answer as simply asserting that the table can always be balanced.

Answer (score 9):

I can't tell if anyone has posted this reference, but [here is an arXiv link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0510065v6.pdf) entitled *ON THE STABILITY OF FOUR-LEGGED TABLES* with the following abstract:

> We prove that a perfect square table with four legs, placed on
>   continuous irregular ground with a local slope of at most 14.4 degrees
>   and later 35 degrees, can be put into equilibrium on the ground by a
>   “rotation” of less than 90 degrees. We also discuss the case of
>   non-square tables and make the conjecture that equilibrium can be
>   found if the four feet lie on a circle.

So your answer is *it has been proven for certain constraints on how irregular the ground it*.

Comment: Interesting constraints. Deserve upvotes, XD incredible someone studied that with a research XD.

Answer (score 6):

**The correct proof**

First we assume that the floor has elevation that is a continuous function of the position bounded between zero and the $p$ where $p$ is some parameter that depends on the shape of the table (see below for details), and that the table legs are lines that end in the points of a square $ABCD$. The problem is then assumed to be to position the table so that all four legs touch (and do not go through) the floor.

In the following method note that every step is physically possible in the sense that the table never intersects the floor.

First note that there is a rotational orientation of the table (based on $p$), such that for any point on the floor we can hold the table in that orientation such that one leg touches the floor at that point. This is possible because we can hold the table sufficiently tilted and above the floor, so that the end of the lowest leg is directly above the desired point, and now lowering the table results in that leg touching the floor first by the intermediate value theorem (IVT) and the tilt. We can assume that $A$ is the end of that leg touching the floor at the chosen point. Now tilt the table around the line through $A$ that is perpendicular to $AB$ and horizontal, such that $B$ goes towards the floor, until the leg ending at $B$ touches the floor by IVT. Tilt the table around the line through $AB$ until a third leg touches the floor by IVT. Note that if the third leg is not there we can tilt some more so that the last leg touches the floor by IVT.

Note that in the above subroutine it is easy to choose the initial orientation of the table such that rotating the table by any angle around the vertical will give yet another initial orientation that works. So we get a function with its inputs being the desired point and the initial rotation around the vertical and its output being a table 'position' with $ABC$ on the floor (and $D$ possibly below). It is not hard to prove that this function is continuous, given some weak conditions on the floor (see below). This is the key.

Perform this subroutine once to get $ABC$ on the floor. To be precise we simply get any three legs on the floor, and then rotate the table such that those legs are the ones that actually have endpoints being $ABC$. Then choose any path $P$ from $A$ to $B$ on the floor. Drag the table on the floor such that $A$ follows $P$. We claim that we can do so with $B,C$ remaining on the floor. This follows from the subroutine's continuity since we can keep the rotation around vertical fixed and just use the subroutine on the points along the path. In fact this is what can actually happen physically if you constrain the table's movements. Now drag the table on the floor such that $A$ remains where it is while $B$ goes to where $C$ originally was. Again we claim that we can keep $B,C$ on the floor in the process of dragging. This is because the subroutine applied to all possible rotations around the vertical gives all possible table 'positions' where $A$ is in that place and $B,C$ are on the floor. In particular, a quarter turn around the vertical gives a table 'position' where $A,B$ are at the original locations of $B,C$, and in that case $D$ is below the floor. By IVT, there is a smallest rotation less than that quarter turn such that the subroutine will give a table 'position' with $D$ exactly on the floor. This means that we can drag the table to move $B$ 'around' $A$ keeping $B,C$ on the floor because of the subroutine's continuity, and before a quarter 'turn' we would have found the solution.

**Table parameter**

Clearly if the table top is much wider than the distance between legs, the method can fail to work simply because the side of the table top hits the floor. In the worst case the legs are so short and the table top has some downward protrusions that reach the plane through the square! In that case certain floors would make the problem impossible. However, as long as there is a plane that completely separates the leg ends from the table top, there will be some suitable parameter $p > 0$ for the above method to work.

Similarly if the legs point outwards, the middle part of the legs may hit the floor if we use the method. Again, for reasonable tables there is some suitable parameter $p$ that works. (No I'm not going to rigorously prove this.)

**Floor conditions**

Also, to ensure that the subroutine works, any sphere with centre on the floor and radius $AB$ must intersect the floor at points that are at unique angles from the centre. I'm not sure whether this condition can be removed without making the solution non-constructive, in the sense that we can easily prove existence of a solution but there may not be a physical method (like the one above) to obtain it systematically from any random starting position.

In any case, this condition is fulfilled by various simpler conditions such as having Lipschitz constant at most $1$.

Comment: Wow. This deserves more upvotes, even if it would be wrong. +1

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek: I'm a mathematician and I can certainly assure you that my answer is the only one that uses IVT correctly. My answer had been downvoted by some people who did not like mathematical correctness, which is also why I quit participating on Puzzling SE.

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is beautiful. $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 3):

**Answer:**

> The answer is no, there exist at least one counter example of floor that prevent the table to be placed, don't get me wrong, it is perfectly possible that the chance to that floor to exists is so low that don't really matters, but I'll show that exists a whole family of floors preventing table placement.

**Strategy:**

> So given I gave a counter-example, no, it is not always possible to place the table

**Proof:(false)**

> Assume the floor seen from aboxe is just a square/rectangle, one of the corners of the square is **almost** (I give a small delta so I can claim the floor to be continuos) centered on a "hole" and the vertical floor section is `1/x`.[image]

**More Info:**

> You can get a table touching on 4 legs if it is a non-squared shape (in example something like a piece of cake), since the table leg's are placed around corners of a rectangle/square, the 4th leg can't however be placed correctly.
>   I builded this answer around Kevin answer, he sais it is possible, however I used his construction to find out that actually is it not possible (you were so near to the solution XD).

**The family of floors**

> All non-linear polar constructed floors, monotonic 2d functions windows that are contained within a quadrant, don't allow the table to be placed. (the family can be actually bigger)

**Reason**

> You can always find 2 points on the surface to get a line, however you place the line, if you turn the table to get the third leg touchin the 4th leg will not be touching.

**What's new**

> Other answers give either a wrong answer (Yes), or mention cases that are either not clear where the solution lies (need constraints, and readers have to figure them out) or have no intuitional proof. I think the one I give here is very easy to reason about.

**EDIT:**

> The construction still holds, but needs some adaptation, as noted in the comments, I can still place legs of the table on 2 elevation rings, however If I skew the floor along 1 axis, and I cut out simmetric planes, I'm no longer able to place the table:
>   [image]

**Conjecture (true, but need proof)**

> Given 2 ellypses of different diameter (same center and not circles), except for  pairs centered on a simmetry axis, there are no pair of parallel lines whose intersections with the 2 ellypses are the corners of a rectangle.

**In the end:**

> We need also to "stretch" the floor in one direction and cut out simmetry axis in additiction to the family of floors I constructed above.

Comment: "The only way to get something with 4 legs to touch 4 points on the floor is by having it to be 'cake piece shaped'." I don't believe this. Why should it be true?

Comment: Well, it was a small inaccuracy, " a sufficient condition to make legs fits is to have a table chake-piece-shaped". I'll edit the answer, the rest is still perfectly valid.

Comment: Well @f'' it is true at least on the `"1/x"` floor.

Comment: A cake-shaped table can be placed on the floor, but that doesn't prove that a square table can't. In fact, there is a way to place a square table on this surface.

Comment: True, however a slight scale along one of the 2 axis (top view) would prevent the table to be placeable.

Comment: You have not proved that.

Comment: @f'' 
 
You are right again XD, if you accept the last statement of the edited answer as a proof, then I now proven that XD (finally)

Comment: No, you haven't. You have only shown that certain ways of placing the table won't work, but you have to prove that *no* ways work.

Comment: Ok, I don't XD but this time at least I'm sure I'm correct, then I changed the name from "proof" to "conjecture" (still the Questioner didn't asked a proof and I think at least I got it more near than any other answer). I started a real proof attemp using line/ellipse intersection but got bored by calculations very soon. (used 2 crossed lines at 90° of angle)

Comment: You're assuming that if the table is placed on the surface, it must be on two ellipses. This is not the case.

Comment: It can't be otherwise. If I assume we have 3 elevation paths, (3 legs at different elevation) then the 4th leg will not be touching the floor even in the circular floor (that was my original assumption that did not kept into account few corner cases). By using an elliptic floor I removed the corner cases too.

Comment: So in short:
`3 ellipsis => the table can't be placed (first part of answer)` then
`2 ellipsis => the table can be placed on circles, but not on ellipsis` wich is the edited version of the answer.. I'm not assuming 2 ellipsis, I'm just checking 2 ellipsis now work because anyway I was already sure 3 ellispis was not allowing placement of the table ;)

Comment: 3 or 4 is not possible on the circular floor, but it is on the elliptical floor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if this counts as lateral thinking, but couldn't you just chop off a leg? Looking at the answers the problem seems to be one leg connecting with the floor preventing the opposite leg doing so.

Comment: But then it wouldn't be a 4-legged table anymore, which goes against the very question itself.

Comment: @McMagister is right: the table has to remain 4-legged and perfectly symmetrical, as stated in the OP. This _does_ count as lateral thinking, I'm afraid.

Comment: @McMagister BTW, you can chop just a part of it ;)

Comment: What with my other question, I don't seem to be able to find a middle ground between overly lateral and overly literal...

Comment: You know what, the table *does* have to remain $4$-legged, but for uniqueness, Imma give you a $(+1)$ :D

Answer (score 1):

You may be asking the wrong question.  As stated, no it isn't always possible to position an 'ideal table' on an uneven floor and guarantee that all four legs have firm contact with the ground.  The real question is it is possible to always distort a floor such that an ideal table *will* wobble.

Start with an 'ideal floor' (perfectly smooth and level) made from soft wood, place your ideal table anywhere.  No wobble.  Now take a hammer and knock out a small uneven plug from the floor under one of the legs.  Now the table wobbles.  Move table and if doesn't wobble, repeat hammer knock out.  Repeat until you have a floor upon which there is no position where the table doesn't wobble.

Given a randomly sized (table width, depth) and a randomly uneven floor, you *might* be able to place the table somewhere it doesn't wobble but you *might* not.  Therefore it isn't *always* possible.

---

**Update:**

I decided to update my answer since people seem to have misunderstood.

I'm not suggesting that the question ask was wrong.  I simple thought that reframing the question might help people see the answer.

I'm not suggest that the floor is continuously moving.  The floor is "uneven" there are lots and lots and lots of ways that a floor can be uneven.  I simply started with an even floor and made it uneven to make a point.

How do I know that my *"repeat until you have ..." loop is guaranteed to terminate?*  Given the problem statement we know there are a finite number of positions available for the table on the floor (there must be some distance, no matter how small that defines a "new" position for the table).  Lets call the number of possible configurations *n*.  Take the set of all uneven floors, in that there has to be at least one floor where there is only one position where the table wobbles (if there were no positions then the floor would be even).  There must also be a floor where there are only two positions where the table wobbles.  One where there are only three positions, etc.  Therefore, there must be at least one floor that has only one position where the table table wobbles.  Start with that floor.  Take hammer and 'unlevel' the floor under one of the legs, call that point *p*.  In order for the loop to never end the change of *p* must lead to a new position which is a rotation around point *p* where the table does not wobble, but there is still only one position on the floor where the table doesn't wobble.  Hit *p* again, repeat.  Since there are only *n* possible positions of the table in the room you cannot repeat the procedure more than *n* times.  Since you are not changing any other points you will by eventually have a floor where there is no position where the table doesn't wobble.  Therefore, there is at least one floor where you can not position the table in a wobble free position.  Thus it is not ALWAY possible to position the table so that it doesn't wobble.

Comment: ...The question he asked is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I agree about the equivalence: if it's possible to construct a floor on which the table cannot fit, then it follows it's not always possible to make the table fit on every floor. But you haven't shown that the procedure of knocking holes in the floor actually terminates with a floor on which the table doesn't fit. So you haven't shown a way to construct (or, in this case, destruct) the floor you're looking for. For example, how do we know that I won't eventually knock a hole in every location, and I'm right back where I started?

Comment: @Steve Jessop, by definition you don't stop if the table doesn't wobble.  Look at it another way, if you position the table so it doesn't wobble I can always 'adjust' the floor so that it does.  The original problem states only that the floor is uneven (not how it is uneven) and that the table 'always' can be positioned to not-wobble.

Comment: I think as per the definitions of the problem by the OP we can safely assume that a continuously moving floor doesn't qualify as a "floor" (not without violating the "no tricks" clause)

Comment: What makes you think that your "repeat until you have ..." loop is guaranteed to terminate?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can solve this question infallibly unless you approach it using a theoretical approach specifically in multivariable calculus. If you reword your question into a mathematically approachable model, then the question goes:

---

Let $m > 0$ be the greatest slope that is acceptable for a "realistic floor." Let $l$ and $w$ be the length and width of the chair.

Define $S$ to be the set of **all** continuous surfaces such that for each surface $S_i$, $|{dz \over {dx}}|,|{dz \over {dy}}| < m$ at every point in $S_i$.

Define the set $P_{A,B}$ be all the possible contact points (x,y,z) between a continuous surface $A$ and a plane $B$, both of which are in $\mathbb R^3$ (the 3rd dimension).

Does $S$ have the property that there always exists a plane $B_i$ such that $P_{S_i, B_i}$ contains 4 contact points that form a rectangle of dimensions $l, w$ when connected?

---

I simply don't have the knowledge to derive and justify the result, and I don't think that kind of infallible solution would be easy to get here; math.stackexchange would be more appropriate.

I have only posed more questions so far, so to make up for this (kind of), I will hypothesize that the answer to the question is no; if I assume that $S$ does have said property for dimensions $l,w$, then the same property must be applicable for really large dimensions and really small dimensions (e.g. where $l,w \in (0, \infty)$ ), and I simply find that unfeasible.

Comment: This is an interesting study in how to make a simple problem more complicated and harder to understand, but it doesn't really answer the question I asked...

Comment: Sorry, translations into math cannot always be simple without losing precision. 

The 4 points of contact must lie on a flat plane, as described by your legs-with-the-same-height description. I define $P_{A,B}$ as the family that those 4 points must lie in. 

If you want to prove that this applies to every realistic surface you can imagine, then you want to define a set of those realistic surfaces for notation purposes. That explains $S$.

Is there anything else that I'm missing? Or can you please explain why your interpretation conflicts with my mathematical translation

Comment: Oh nevermind, I understand what you mean. I intended to make a comment to offer this as help, but having only 1 point limits my options.

Comment: That's fair enough. I would flag a mod to convert this to a comment, but it's way too long for a comment! I actually know more than enough maths to formulate this in some incomprehensible way, but I liked the simplicity and practicality of the original problem.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is certainly no, the best way to think about this is in terms of basic linear algebra, or if math is not your strong point just in terms of a 3d graph.

Your questions translates to "for any four points in 3d space, does there always exist a single 2d plane containing them all". For our problem: the four points are the bottoms of the four legs and the 2d plane is the floor.

We can certainly put any three points in the same plane by just drawing lines between them and defining that as the plane, but we will not always be able to add the fourth (in fact almost every other point will not be in this plane).

To visualise this consider the four points of the form (x,y,z) in Cartesian (normal) coordinates:

- a = (0,0,0)    i.e. this signifies x=0, y=0, z=0
- b = (1,0,0)
- c = (0,1,0)
- d = (1,1,1)

Clearly, a,b and c all lie in the (x,y)-plane, we will call this the floor. However, d is by definition NOT in the (x,y)-plane as the x value is set to zero. It lies exclusively in the (y,z)-plane and will always be shifted away by one unit no matter how much you rotate the points.

Try this out by plotting each of these points in the following link:

[point/graph plotter](http://hotmath.com/learning_activities/interactivities/3dplotter.swf)

Rotate the graph around and line 3 points up into the same plane, the third will always appear a unit of 1 to the side.

I hope this helps.

Edit:

I changed the points to the "table-like" layout

Comment: Maths _is_ my strong point, don't worry! You're right that 4 points don't define a plane, but you couldn't make a perfectly symmetrical 4-legged table with ends at those 4 points.

Comment: Err, the problem was that the table is perfect (so the for ends of the legs *by definition* are on a plane) while the floor is not (the floor isn't a plane, but a general continuous surface).

Comment: @celtschk is right. I don't know why this has got so many upvotes.

Comment: You show that there exist a non-valid position on a floor you don't showed all positions are invalid.